# MySQL via SSL on VPC private subnet

Tags: mysql, security, ssl, amazon-vpc, networking

Is an SSL connection recommended when connecting to a MySQL database server via a private subnet?

SSL provides encryption but SSL causes a performance hit.  The MySQL database server only serves the VPC private subnet.  I can't see a reason to include SSL for this connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's really something you will need to judge for yourself based on your knowledge of your environment and research into the vulerabilities of your environment.  Basically you need to analyze the risk of someone capturing the network traffic on the subnet.  If you feel the risk is low enough to not justify the performance hit, then don't use SSL.  If you feel there is a risk OR if your data is at all sensitive then you should consider using the secure connection.